# How many independent K-Plexes there are in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

[K-plex](http://faculty.ucr.edu/~hanneman/nettext/C11_Cliques.html#kplex) - A k-plex is a relaxation of the clique problem. where each vertex needs to have ties to all but k other members.

Assuming I have a k-plex. I need to count the number of distinct maximal  k-1-plexes are in the graph.

For example: assuming k=1. and my graph is square with 4 vertices. 
G= {v1,v2,v3,v4}
E= {(v1,v2),(v2,v3),(v3,v4),(v4,v1)}

for k-1 = 0.
There are the following maximal 0-plexes (0-plex is a clique)
{v1,v2}, {v2,v3},{v3,v4},{v1,v4}

we cannot add any other vertex to {v1,v2} because v3 is not connected to v1, and v4 is not connected to v2.

So in this case we will have 4 maximal k-plexes.

Now, assuming that in the initial graph we have also the edge (v1,v3). in this case we will have only 2 maximal 0-plexes: {v1,v2,v3} and {v1,v3,v4}

In this case each vertex that was not connected to exactly one vertex (i.e. its degree of disconnection was k) was mapped to a different (k-1)-plex.

How can I get the upper bound on the number of (k-1)k-plexes in a graph, given the number of nodes that are disconnected from exactly k other nodes?

Comment: Just to clarify, your definition of a $k$-plex $G$ requires all vertices of $G$ to have degree $|V(G)|-k$? So a $k$-plex is simply an $n-k$-regular graph on $n$ vertices?

Comment: Never mind, I did some searching and assume now that you mean each vertex has degree **at least** $|V(G)|-k$.